# How to force image to load first

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have a photo gallery which, depending on the number of pictures, can take some time to load. I have a .gif loading image that I have set to appear while the gallery is loading. However, for some reason the .gif itself takes many seconds to appear on the screen.

How can I force the .gif to load before other images on the page so that the "loading" image is seen by the user right off the bat?

Here is the site [Photo Gallery](http://daemondeveloper.com/photography/gallery.php)

Comment: The problem isn't really in when the image is loaded; it's the size of the image that's causing it to take some time. Each of those JPGs is over 100K in size. Use thumbnails instead of just scaling down the full-size JPGs.

Comment: What do you mean by loading it first? Waiting with all other images until it's loaded or just start loading it first?

Comment: well i don't mind the load time of the actual images in the gallery, its just the .gif i use as a loading img that is taking a while

Comment: i wanna load it first. before everything else.

Comment: I don't see why you need a loading gif. Page loads so fast for me it would be completely pointless...

Comment: yes right now. but not if theres 100+ images in a gallery the load time goes to between 10-15 seconds

Comment: The password to your gallery is 'password'. Nice. :) The loading gif seemed to work fine for me... Is the gif part of the DOM on page load, or are you appending it when loading happens?

Comment: Just follow Blazemonger's instructions and page will not be so "heavy". Also, check your js code. I think scrolling on this page is a bit "lazy". And arrows in gallery preview.

Comment: yeah i have been trying to figure out the "lazy" scrolling and arrows. can't get it tho. Idk how to check if the javascript is still executing somewhere

Comment: You can add a loading class to the gallery div that has the gif centered in the background. Then use jquery to find the last image and check if it is loaded using `$('lastimage').load(function() { $('#gallery').removeClass('.loadingclass');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of your images is the entire problem. The background, the full-size photos, it all adds up to a mess of bandwidth. Even on broadband it takes too long because there's so many images that have to be downloaded separately.

Replace your giant background with two small PNGs and use small thumbnails for the actual gallery. Your problem will disappear.

Comment: by two small pngs to do you mean one for the left black design and one for the right side? also, what is the best way to use thumbnails? do I need 2 image files for each photo or can I use just one physical image file?

Comment: Yes, one background image for a DIV positioned on the left and one for the right -- a single large JPEG is unnecessary. Thumbnails should be separate images, no larger than they need to be (don't scale and crop in your code) and as compressed as you can make them without making them obviously blurred.

Comment: Ok I will try to change it so there are thumbnails instead. I feel like there should be a better way because introducing thumbnails makes my image managing system much more complicated. Since this is a photography site, the images are all added using a PHP page i created, not manually

Comment: ["Faster, better, cheaper -- pick any two."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_management_triangle) For what it's worth, there are more robust PHP gallery systems that will create the thumbnails for you, but they're also much more complicated to install. (I lack the experience to recommend one, though.)

Comment: Ok, I am pretty inexperienced, only known HTML, javascript, CSS for about 10 months and PHP for about 4 so I was attempting to create my own management system from scratch. I should have known I was doing it all wrong. lol

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Ajax call to load the gif

Step 2: Load the rest in the ajax callback

Comment: To improve your answer, some sample code would be helpful. :-)